# Is this correct approach to submitting JSON via HTTP POST to a java Web Server?

Tags: java, android, json, post, android-asynctask

I construct the `JSON` Object

```
JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject geoJsonObj = new JSONObject();
    try {
        jsonobj.put("action","put-point");
        geoJsonObj.put("lng", longitude);
        geoJsonObj.put("lat", latitude);
        geoJsonObj.put("rangeKey", rangeKey);
        geoJsonObj.put("schoolName", "TESTSCHOOL535353");
        jsonobj.put("request", geoJsonObj);


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I Execute an `AsyncTask`

```
    new HTTPtoServer().execute(jsonobj);
```

The `AsyncTask` looks like this:

```
private class HTTPtoServer extends AsyncTask<JSONObject, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(JSONObject... params) {

        //Prepare HTTP Post Client
        DefaultHttpClient myClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost myPost = new HttpPost(ElasticBeanStalkEndpoint);

        StringEntity se = null;

                Log.v("TEST","TEST");

        try {
            se = new StringEntity(params[0].toString());
            Log.v("MY SE", se.toString());

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        myPost.setEntity(se);

        HttpResponse httpresponse = null;
        try {
            httpresponse = myClient.execute(myPost);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String responseText = null;
        try {
            responseText = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return responseText;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
        Log.v("MY STRING", s);
    }
 }
```

However my JSON Object appears to never be "sending"?
Or maybe it is, but in an incorrect format?
The `Java` Tomcat server doesn't seem to be doing anything with the data?

My `StringEntity` results in :

```
org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity@528111f8
```

When I do `se.toString()`... Is this correct?

I seem to be a bit confused.

SERVER CODE:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
    try {
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        String line = null;
        BufferedReader reader = request.getReader();

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            buffer.append(line);
        }

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(buffer.toString());
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String action = jsonObject.getString("action");
        log("action: " + action);
        JSONObject requestObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("request");
        log("requestObject: " + requestObject);

        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("put-point")) {
            putPoint(requestObject, out);
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("get-point")) {
            getPoint(requestObject, out);
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("update-point")) {
            updatePoint(requestObject, out);
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("query-rectangle")) {
            queryRectangle(requestObject, out);
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("query-radius")) {
            queryRadius(requestObject, out);
        } else if (action.equalsIgnoreCase("delete-point")) {
            deletePoint(requestObject, out);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        e.printStackTrace(pw);
        log(sw.toString());
    }
}

private void putPoint(JSONObject requestObject, PrintWriter out) throws IOException, JSONException {
    GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(requestObject.getDouble("lat"), requestObject.getDouble("lng"));
    AttributeValue rangeKeyAttributeValue = new AttributeValue().withS(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    AttributeValue schoolNameKeyAttributeValue = new AttributeValue().withS(requestObject.getString("schoolName"));

    PutPointRequest putPointRequest = new PutPointRequest(geoPoint, rangeKeyAttributeValue);
    putPointRequest.getPutItemRequest().addItemEntry("schoolName", schoolNameKeyAttributeValue);

    PutPointResult putPointResult = geoDataManager.putPoint(putPointRequest);

    printPutPointResult(putPointResult, out);
}
```

Comment: what you exactly want to do with this?you want to send data over to server in json object format or else

Comment: I am sending a `JSON` object which specifies a "method" to be called on the Java server. Would posting the code for that help too?

Comment: So it takes in that `JSON` object, extracts the secondary inner `JSON` and runs that `putpoint` method that I added above on the webserver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like that.

```
JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
JSONObject geoJsonObj = new JSONObject();
try {
    jsonobj.put("action","put-point");
    geoJsonObj.put("lng", longitude);
    geoJsonObj.put("lat", latitude);
    geoJsonObj.put("rangeKey", rangeKey);
    geoJsonObj.put("schoolName", "TESTSCHOOL535353");
    jsonobj.put("request", geoJsonObj);


 } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
new SendData().execute(jsonobj.toString());

public class SendData extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Double>{  
  String response="";  
    @Override  
    protected Double doInBackground(String... params) {  

            postData(params[0]);  

    }  




    public void postData(String jsondata)  {  

        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header  
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  

         HttpPost httpPost=new HttpPost("url");  
        try {  
            // Add your data  
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();  
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json",jsondata));  


            httpPost.setEntity((HttpEntity) new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

            // Execute HTTP Post Request  
            HttpResponse res = httpclient.execute(httpPost);  
             InputStream content = res.getEntity().getContent();  

              BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));  
              String s = "";  
              while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {  
                response += s;  
              }  
              System.out.println("response from server"+response);  


        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        } catch (IOException e) {  

            // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        }  
    }  
}
```

SERVER SIDE-

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {  

String jsondata=request.getParameter("json");
```

//now parse your data from json

```
try {
        JSONObject JsonObject=new JSONObject(jsondata);  
        JSONObject object=JsonObject.getJSONObject("request");  
        String action=object.getString("action");  
        String lng=object.getString("lng");  
        String lat=object.getString("lat");  
        String rangeKey=object.getString("rangeKey");  
        String schoolName=object.getString("schoolName");  

    } catch (JSONException e) {  
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }
```

}

I hope this will help you...!

Comment: Hey vikas balyan, I tried out this implementation and I am still not seeing any results in my database?

Comment: @Tukajo are you getting value of jsondata serverside.?

Comment: @Tukajo, Here its woking fine.

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

```
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(PROJECT_ID, params[0]));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(BROKER_ID,params[1]));
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));
String output;
StringBuilder responseJsonStr = new StringBuilder();

while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    responseJsonStr.append(output);
}

String queryString = Utils.getQueryString(nameValuePairs);
System.out.println("Query String "+URL +"&"+queryString);
//System.out.println("response Json String "+responseJsonStr );

if(!StringUtils.startsWith(responseJsonStr.toString(), "[")) {
    responseJsonStr.insert(0,"[");
    responseJsonStr.append("]");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public String getJson(Context applicationContext,String url) {
        InputStream is = null;
        String result = "";
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("response_key",PrefernceSettings.getRestKey()));
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("response_request","auto_payments"));
            Log.e("",String.valueOf(nameValuePairs));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
            }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }
        try{
            if(is != null){
                result = convertInputStreamToString(is);
                Log.e("result", result);
            }else{
                result = "Did not work!";
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
        return result;
    }
    public  String convertInputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) {
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        String line = "";
        String result = "";
        try {
            while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
                result += line;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            inputStream.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using this function:

```
    public boolean postJSON(JSONObject jsonobj) {

        try {
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost("YOUR URL HERE");
            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());
            // Set HTTP parameters
            httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
            httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip");
            //Send Http request
            HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String resonseStr = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            return getResponse(resonseStr);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
```

0D
where `getResponse` is a function that gets the response string and parses it and returns true or false according to how you define the web service.